# Not able to access mysql using script

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting the following error when trying to access a MySQL table :

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

But, I can login with root when using `mysql` in the command line.

Comment: could you post your PHP connection script? - and you should probably be using a password on your database

Comment: is this a new installation?

Answer (score 0):

That is the normal behaviour. You set a root password for your database so from now on you can't access it without password. That is why it reports:

```
Access denied for user 'root@localhost' (using password: no )
```

Obviously when you give the password with the -p switch you succeed.

Answer (score -1):

You should set up a password for root!
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/resetting-permissions.html